# Django 1.10 Delete large cascade querySet

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm trying to delete all objects from a large queryset. Here is my models.py

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db import models


class Fund(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False, null=False)
    start_date = models.DateField(default=None, blank=False, null=False)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name


class FundData(models.Model):

    fund = models.ForeignKey(Fund, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date = models.DateField(default=None, blank=False, null=False)
    value = models.FloatField(default=None, blank=True, null=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "{} --- Data: {} --- Value: {} ".format(str(self.fund), str(self.date), str(self.value))
```

But when I try to delete all records the query take too much time and mysql is being timed out.

```
Fund.objects.all().delete()
```

- What is the best way to manage this operation inside a view?
- There is a way to do that calling a django command from terminal?

Answer (score 1):

First of all you can change the timeout time of MySQL by edditing `settings.py`

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        ...
        OPTIONS = {
            'connect_timeout': 5, # your timeout time
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

The reasons why `.delete()` may be slow are:

1. Django has to ensure cascade deleting functions properly. It has to look for foreign keys to your models
2. Django has to somehow handle pre and post-save signals for your models

If you are sure that your models don't have cascade deleting or any signals to be handled, you can try to use private `_raw_delete` as follows:

```
queryset._raw_delete(queryset.db)
```

You can find more details on it [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/_modules/django/db/models/query/)

Comment: My models have on_delete=models.CASCADE. Deleting all Funds I delete also all related FundData (thousands for each Fund). What they mean with "there is no protection for cascades." ?

Comment: I'm not really sure that changing connect_timeout will help. From mysql docs: "The number of seconds that the mysqld server waits for a connect packet before responding with Bad handshake. The default value is 10 seconds. Increasing the connect_timeout value might help if clients frequently encounter errors of the form Lost connection to MySQL server at 'XXX', system " .

Comment: @Andrea I think that "there is no protection for cascades" means that they just won't be deleted. You haven't pasted exact traceback so it's hard to say which timeout you have. Don't you think that this will help https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/gone-away.html ?

Comment: Ok thanks I'm agree with you, I Getting “Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction” , this maybe because a mysql process was previously locking db performing the long delete operation and getting stuck

Answer (score 1):

Finally I got a simple solution to delete all cascade object breaking down the macro deletion operation preferring delete Fund objects one by one. Because it is a really long operation (approximately 1 second for each object for thousands objects) I assigned it to a celery worker. Slow but safe I think, if someone got a better solution please let me know!

```
@shared_task
def reset_funds():
    for fund in Fund.objects.all():
        print "Delete Fund: {}".format(fund.name)
        fund.delete()
    return "All Funds Deleted!"
```